Is it possible to make cabbage soup from coleslaw?
If it is possible to make cabbage soup from coleslaw, the. what other ingredients would you add?
Please note that the coleslaw I am using is mostly cabbage and mayonnaise.
Too much coleslaw was made; there is a lot of extra.

In the restaurant we always used leftover coleslaw as fried cabbage.

If you rinse off the mayo, you've just got shredded cabbage and carrot. You can now  follow a basic stew recipe; https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/cabbage-soup

The mayonnaise and possibly all acids (vinegar, lemon juice, if used) can be a challenge. But if you’re just planning on using up leftovers to avoid food waste, you can rinse off the marinade and while you don’t have perfect fresh cabbage, you can certainly work with what you have.
A “basic” cabbage soup would be made like most vegetable soups or stews, often based on carrots, celery or celeriac, some allium component like onions or leeks and in some regions, parsley roots. Then topped with water or broth, and cooked into a stew.
I recommend you check a few recipes and you’ll soon find out that for many the basic approach is at least very similar.
If your cabbage is rather acidic after rinsing, you can manage that in two ways, either going with the acidity, which could mean adding some tomato and/or topping with some sour cream or masking it by being more generous with those components that bring some sweetness (carrots and onions), adding a small bit of sugar, honey, maple syrup and in any case, cooking the whole batch a bit longer which will cause the flavors to mellow more.
